# How fill a database mysql with examples data?

Tags: mysql, database-performance

i'm looking for a software that i can use to fill a mysql db (structure created by joomla, drupal or any CMS or script) with samples data for tot MB, so i can decide to put 400 MB of data in my tables to test my db and mysql engine. Is there something like this? Thanks very much ;) Nik

Comment: Having xMB of data doesn't help you test something unless it has a particular distribution of values that matches up with what you're trying to test.

Comment: He's asking for sample data for specific applications, which I think is a reasonable question to ask.

Comment: Unfortunately you need to be far more specific than this - what KIND of data to put into which tables - and writing scripts to generate it can be quite an onerous task. I spent three months on this last year.

Answer (score 2):

I know drupal 6 specifically the devel module allows you to generate random dummy text:
http://drupal.org/project/devel

Answer (score 2):

Just answering to help someone who've landed here after gloogling for a similar subject......

1. go to http://kedar.nitty-witty.com/blog/generate-dummy-test-data-for-mysql-using-routines and download the sql code
2. enter at the sql client and load

   sql> source '/my/downloaded/script';
3. fill your tables

   sql> use test;

   sql> call pupulate('test','tablename',1000,'N');

now you have 1000 rows in your table 'test.tablename'

Answer (score 0):

if you put your data into a comma separated value file, you can use the LOAD DATA command.
Here is a [page](http://www.modwest.com/help/kb.phtml?qid=253&cat=6) discussing how to import CSV data into mysql

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/importfile.csv' 
INTO TABLE test_table 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
(field1, filed2, field3);
```

here is a [shortcut](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlimport.html) to run the LOAD DATA command.

To import from joomla, drupal, etc, you might need to export and convert into csv.

Answer (score 0):

you can create one sample db , take your dump with:

```
#mysqldump databasename > dumpfile.sql
```

then use anywhere on any database using:

```
#mysql databasename < dumpfile.sql
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try http://filldb.info/
Automatically generate data and fill your database tables with dummy data.